# Scaling issue when rendering to half size texture

Tags: graphics, direct3d

A portion of my rendering pass is performed on a render target that is set to exactly half the viewport size of my main swap chain.

The issue is that the render target is only displaying a quarter of the scene I am rendering. Something like this:

[image]

If I change the render target's dimensions to match the swap chain, everything works... And, I've confirmed in the graphics debugger that the render target is the right size: w/2 and h/2.

**What am I missing here?**

As it seems to be an issue with how the vertices are transformed, does the projection matrix need to change even though the aspect ratio has not been altered?

Comment: Did you remember to set the viewport to W/2 x H/2 as well?  The viewport determines the output region for any render target, not just the main swap chain.  Also, your vertices shouldn't need to change - the logical output position still should span (-1:1) for both X and Y.  Without more info it's tough to diagnose the problem.

Comment: This was it. I needed to use RSSetViewport. Please move to an answer, and I will accept.